# PHP XML-Export as file download

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

i have written a script that prints a XML file to the screen but I want it to open a download dialog so that i could save it as a file.

how could i do that?

thnx!

the script:

```
<?php
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
print "\n <data>";
...
print "\n </data>";
?>
```

Comment: Definitely not an answer to your question, but I'd recommend using some library/class to generate xml instead of constructing it 'manually' (e.g SimpleXML - used quite often in Drupal code, or DOMDocument if you have more sophisticated needs). This saves tons of work.

Comment: @headkit: If you have written a module for this. Can You please give me the code.If you reply back I will give by mail id. Thanks

Comment: no module was created, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting the headers right:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.xml"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
print "\n <data>";
...
print "\n </data>";
?>
```

Comment: You might try this again putting an `ob_end_clean();` call in front of the header declarations. From your tags I assume this happens in a Drupal context, and Drupal might interfere by already having set some headers upfront. Clearing the output buffer might make a difference.

Comment: Do you get any warnings that the header were already sent? Look in your apache log in /var/log/apache2/ or so. In that case you can try Henrik's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following to force the browser to show the "Save As..." dialog:
The browser shows a "Save As..." dialog for content types that it doesn't know how to interpret / display, or when it is instructed to in the headers. Just know the correct headers and you can specify to download it, the default filename, content type and how it should be cached.

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$xml .= "\n <data>";

// Create the rest of your XML Data...

$xml .= "\n </data>";
downloader($xml, 'yourFile.xml', 'application/xml');
```

The function code:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('downloader'))
 {
  function downloader($data, $filename = true, $content = 'application/x-octet-stream')
   {
    // If headers have already been sent, there is no point for this function.
    if(headers_sent()) return false;
    // If $filename is set to true (or left as default), treat $data as a filepath.
    if($filename === true)
     {
      if(!file_exists($data)) return false;
      $data = file_get_contents($data);
     }
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE") !== false)
     {
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Content-Type: '.$content);
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
     }
    else
     {
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Content-Type: '.$content);
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Pragma: no-cache');
      header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
     }
    // Send file to browser, and terminate script to prevent corruption of data.
    exit($data);
   }
 }
```